Excel - Summarising the number of days within anniversary brackets based on a start date
Simply put, I'm seeking to summarise the number of days that fall within anniversary dates based on some initial date (Issue_date) until an end date (Good_To_Date). My second step was calculating the number of days within those brackets to a future date (Safety_Date) and finding the difference.
I'd like to account for as much detail in the number of days as possible, so I can't base it on a 360/30 year and need to account for leap years.
I've included an example in the figure below. More detail on the problem for context:

The problem relates to holding on to a mineral exploration claim with an area in hectares.
-The longer a claim is held, the more expensive it becomes, and I'm looking to complete budget forecasting for holding on to a claim for some number of days/months/years after the current Good_To_Date.
When a claim is initially staked, its Good_To_Date is one year from the day it was staked. For example, if staked on 2020/02/06, the GTD is 2021/02/06.
Moving the GTD to subsequent years is the given cost (i.e. $5) per hectare per number of years.
If the desired expiration date change crosses an anniversary threshold, then the remainder of the 'time' is charged at the higher rate (i.e. crossing the 3rd-anniversary line goes from $5/ha to $10/ha.)
Once a claim has had expenditure on it past the 7th anniversary, the rate flattens at $20/ha.
The GTD doesn't necessarily need to be changed by an entire year, so the calculations must be done by days rather than years.

Schematic Diagram
I can check some of the results by partially submitting an expenditure report to the gov't and have been able to get within 0.01%, which  I can put down to rounding somewhere, but others are out by 25%, and I can't for the life of me figure out where the errors are hiding. A workaround would be to do this for every claim, but there are hundreds and some we have an interest in but don't own and can't run this dummy load. Plus, checking multiple scenarios becomes... fun.
The most elegant solution would be to determine the number of days within each anniversary bracket (based on the Issue_Date brackets) after the Good_To_Date and calculate the fees involved, but that might be the second step after confidently solving for the number of days.



Claim_Name
Area_ha
Issued_Date
Good_To_Date
Safety_Date
Actual_Cost




Claim_1
59.128
2005/07/11
2026/06/03
2026/09/01
291.59


Claim_4
396.7236
2007/07/03
2026/08/29
2026/09/01
48.91



My initial attempts involved solving how many days fell within each bracket in the Issue_Date:Good_To_Date time frame, calculating the final cost, and subtracting it from the final price within the Issue_Date:Safety_Date time frame. I ran into issues when I had new expiry dates just before or after an anniversary bracket, which might be how I have Excel handling days.
I also tried using ChatGPT and doing it through Python, which will be my final result, so I can include this as part of another workflow I have, but I need to understand some more details about date handling before I go back down that road.
I also spoke directly with the gov't department which administers this, but they were unhelpful.
Edit:
I've included a more detailed diagram here:
Detailed Schematic
The equation I've included there is:
(1936.6743 ha * (243 days / 365.25) * $10/ha/yr) + (1936.6743 ha * (353 days/365.25) * $15/ha/yr) = $40,960.46  Actual from gov't = $40,988.50
This includes 243 days in the $10/ha/yr bracket and 353 days in the $15/ha/yr bracket. The result is 99.93% of the official government number.
I've included the fee schedule below:
Gov't Fee Breakdown and Wording

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

What will help the most would be showing exactly how you would calculate it manually for the two examples and explaining each step of the calculation. It isn't clear how you arrived at Actual_Cost based on your explanation.

It would be good to have a diagram that includes the Issue Date, Good To Date and Safety Date all labelled, and then show which range is the number of days that needs to be calculated.

@Adam W. - The actual cost is what I get from the gov't website, which I've been double checking the results against, rather than something I calculate. I'll include my calculations in an edit above.
Michael - I'll redo the diagram!

It looks like you want to calculate the cost in extending from Good_To_Date to Safety_Date, where the cost of both dates is calculated from the Issued Date, using the increasing cost/year/hectare based on the number of days within each anniversary period and the corresponding cost for each anniversary period.
This works for the first example based on $20 per year per hectare: (2026/09/01 - 2026/06/03) / 365 * 20 * 59.128 = 291.59. However the 2nd example looks to be based on $15 per year: (2026/09/01 - 2026/08/29) / 365 * 15 * 396.7236 = 48.91.
This doesn't align with your explanation of what the cost/year/hectare should be after the number of years since the Issued Date. So at this point, this doesn't seem like an Excel question as much as trying to understand the algorithm.
If your examples are correct as per the sample expenditure reports supplied to the govt, then I'm guessing it's because you've missed a rule, causing you to use $20/year/hectare where it should still be only $15/year/hectare in the 2nd example. This would explain the 25% discrepancy in some cases. There may be a condition where it flattens to $15 per year instead of $20 per year.

I agree that I'm likely missing some of the algorithm or misunderstanding their wording. I'm also probably not explaining it very well, I've been bashing my head against the wall on this for a bit, and am likely not seeing the forest for the trees.

We can't really help until the logic is understood. Right now, in Claim_4 in your example, do you know why that extension is charging $15/ha/yr even though it's in the 19th year?
